# I need to make a JavaScript function which will be invoked when user clicks on the “Search” button

Tags: javascript, html, xml

The function reads the item name, and
processes the order.xml data and displays all order's item id and customer id that their item_name is matched. It also has to do a partial search, meaning if someone puts in only a letter or word, it will include that in the search result. Each order can have multiple items (in this case 1 or 2).

Here is the HTML page without the search working:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Project 1- Q8</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
  <label for="textfield">Enter Item Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Search">
</p>
<h3>List of all information about the item</h3>
<p id="pend"></p>
<script>
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  var search = document.getElementById("textfield");
  var filter = search.value;
  button.onclick = function(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "order.xml", false);
  xhttp.send();
  xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
  var output="<table width='229' border='1'>";
  var customerid = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("customerid")
  var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
  var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");
  output+="<td width='135'><b>Customer Id</td><td width='78'><b>Item Id</td>"
  for(i = 0; i < customerid.length ;i++)
  {
    output += "<tr>";
    output += "<td>" + customerid[i].innerHTML + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + item[i].getAttribute("itemid") + "</td>";
    output += "</tr>";
  }
  output +="</table>";
  document.getElementById("pend").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the XML page with all the info it takes from:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Q5.xsl"?> 
<orders> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>2384</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="SD93"> 
            <name>Flying By Roller Skates</name> 
            <price>25.00</price> 
            <qty>25</qty> 
        </item> 
        <item instock="N" itemid="B12"> 
            <name>Bounce-o Ball</name> 
            <price>.35</price> 
            <qty>150</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>5268</customerid> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="Q52"> 
            <name>Crash N Burn Skis</name> 
            <price>20</price> 
            <qty>10</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>3384</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="PS93"> 
            <name>All Star Shoe</name> 
            <price>55.00</price> 
            <qty>12</qty> 
        </item> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="M12"> 
            <name>All Star Hat</name> 
            <price>44.35</price> 
            <qty>15</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>9008</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="N" itemid="F32"> 
            <name>Fancy Shirt</name> 
            <price>120</price> 
            <qty>100</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order>
    <!--New Orders Added-->
    <order> 
        <customerid>9837</customerid> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="L9"> 
            <name>Water Bottle</name> 
            <price>20</price> 
            <qty>2</qty> 
        </item>
        <item instock="Y" itemid="B77"> 
            <name>Backpack</name> 
            <price>50</price> 
            <qty>5</qty> 
        </item>
    </order> 

    <order> 
        <customerid>7777</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="N" itemid="E001"> 
            <name>Nike Black Hat</name> 
            <price>35</price> 
            <qty>1</qty> 
        </item>
        <item instock="N" itemid="I28"> 
            <name>Headset</name> 
            <price>100</price> 
            <qty>3</qty> 
        </item>
    </order> 

    <order> 
        <customerid>1234</customerid> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="P619"> 
            <name>Large Suitcase</name> 
            <price>399</price> 
            <qty>1</qty> 
        </item>
        <item instock="Y" itemid="U123"> 
            <name>Sharpener</name> 
            <price>5</price> 
            <qty>10</qty> 
        </item>
    </order> 
</orders>
```

Comment: You need to do `var filter = search.value;` inside the `onclick` function. Otherwise you're getting the value when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks.

Comment: You also never use `filter` to check whether an item matches.

Comment: Ah ya, i had that in the one on my pc, but for some reason, it didn't paste right, fixed that, idk how to implement it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `i` as an index into `customerid`, `item`, and `name`, because there can be multiple items for each customer.

You should loop over the `order` elements, and then loop over `item` within that. Then you can check whether that item name contains the filter string when deciding to include it in the result.

You need to set `filter` in the `onclick` function so you use the value that the user has entered before clicking.

Synchronous AJAX is deprecated. You should use asynchronous mode, and display the table in the `onload` function.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var search = document.getElementById("textfield");
button.onclick = function() {
  var filter = search.value.toLowerCase();

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "order.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    var output = "<table width='229' border='1'>";
    var orders = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("order");
    output += "<td width='135'><b>Customer Id</td><td width='78'><b>Item Id</td>"
    for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      let order = orders[i];
      let customerid = order.getElementsByTagName("customerid")[0];
      let items = order.getElementsByTagName("item");
      for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        if (items[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
          output += "<tr>";
          output += "<td>" + customerid.innerHTML + "</td>";
          output += "<td>" + items[i].getAttribute("itemid") + "</td>";
          output += "</tr>";
        }
      }
    }
    output += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("pend").innerHTML = output;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project 1- Q8</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Enter Item Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
    <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Search">
  </p>
  <h3>List of all information about the item</h3>
  <p id="pend"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not very helpful, what specifically is wrong? What debugging have you done?

Comment: I've slowly removed every part besides just making the table display, and not even that works.

Comment: If you put a console.log call in the onload function, do you see the message?

Comment: first, it was that it was defined as items, not item, after that change, it's saying this:                                 Uncaught TypeError: items.getAttribute is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onload (Q8.html:38)

Comment: `item` should be `items[i]`. I probably had an earlier edit where I declared that variable.

Comment: k so I readded everything else now, since the table showed up (also it has to be items[j], not items [i], and now the if statement has an error :             Uncaught TypeError: items[j].getElementsByTagName(...)[0].toLowerCase is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onload (Q8.html:35)

Comment: I was missing `.innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, it finally works, sorry for the late response, and sorry for being a bit rude, still fairly new with all of this.