# The code is suppose to search the xml page and pull out the item id and customer id of the orders that the user types the item name of

Tags: javascript, html, xml

But when I click on search, it does nothing. It should take the letter or word that the person put in the search bar, check each item name tag in the XML, and print out any the match somewhat to the filter. The XML code cannot be modified, only the html.
Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Project 1- Q8</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
  <label for="textfield">Enter Item Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Search">
</p>
<h3>List of all information about the item</h3>
<p id="pend"></p>
<script>
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
var search = document.getElementById("textfield");
button.onclick = function() {
  var filter = search.value.toLowerCase();

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "order.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    var output = "<table width='229' border='1'>";
    var orders = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("order");
    output += "<td width='135'><b>Customer Id</td><td width='78'><b>Item Id</td>"
    for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      let order = orders[i];
      let customerid = order.getElementsByTagName("customerid")[0];
      let items = order.getElementsByTagName("item");
      for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        if (item.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
          output += "<tr>";
          output += "<td>" + customerid.innerHTML + "</td>";
          output += "<td>" + item.getAttribute("itemid") + "</td>";
          output += "</tr>";
        }
      }
    }
    output += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("pend").innerHTML = output;
  }
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the XML code, which shouldn't be modified at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Q5.xsl"?> 
<orders> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>2384</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="SD93"> 
            <name>Flying By Roller Skates</name> 
            <price>25.00</price> 
            <qty>25</qty> 
        </item> 
        <item instock="N" itemid="B12"> 
            <name>Bounce-o Ball</name> 
            <price>.35</price> 
            <qty>150</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>5268</customerid> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="Q52"> 
            <name>Crash N Burn Skis</name> 
            <price>20</price> 
            <qty>10</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>3384</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="PS93"> 
            <name>All Star Shoe</name> 
            <price>55.00</price> 
            <qty>12</qty> 
        </item> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="M12"> 
            <name>All Star Hat</name> 
            <price>44.35</price> 
            <qty>15</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order> 
    <order> 
        <customerid>9008</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="N" itemid="F32"> 
            <name>Fancy Shirt</name> 
            <price>120</price> 
            <qty>100</qty> 
        </item> 
    </order>
    <!--New Orders Added-->
    <order> 
        <customerid>9837</customerid> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="L9"> 
            <name>Water Bottle</name> 
            <price>20</price> 
            <qty>2</qty> 
        </item>
        <item instock="Y" itemid="B77"> 
            <name>Backpack</name> 
            <price>50</price> 
            <qty>5</qty> 
        </item>
    </order> 

    <order> 
        <customerid>7777</customerid> 
        <status>pending</status> 
        <item instock="N" itemid="E001"> 
            <name>Nike Black Hat</name> 
            <price>35</price> 
            <qty>1</qty> 
        </item>
        <item instock="N" itemid="I28"> 
            <name>Headset</name> 
            <price>100</price> 
            <qty>3</qty> 
        </item>
    </order> 

    <order> 
        <customerid>1234</customerid> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <item instock="Y" itemid="P619"> 
            <name>Large Suitcase</name> 
            <price>399</price> 
            <qty>1</qty> 
        </item>
        <item instock="Y" itemid="U123"> 
            <name>Sharpener</name> 
            <price>5</price> 
            <qty>10</qty> 
        </item>
    </order> 
</orders>
```

Comment: Isn't this the code I wrote for you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687414/i-need-to-make-a-javascript-function-which-will-be-invoked-when-user-clicks-on-t ? If it's not working, post a comment there and we can try to resolve it.

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/234215

Answer (score 1):

I was debugging this for you. In the inner loop, that goes through `items` within an `order`, item is not defined. You need to add `let item = items[j];`.

Then, on the line in the if statement, you call `.toLowerCase` on an element, not on a string.
you might want to change the condition to:

```js
if (item.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
  ...
}
```